# Git shall we use push or merger to remote master after changes done to local master?

Tags: android, git

I have clone an android project from git and I have created a local branch called `devBranch` from `master`.

I have done many changes in `devBranch` and I have pushed it remotely as well.

Now once I've finished with all the changes in `devBranch` I have merged those changes to the master local branch.

Now I want to push those new changes in local master to remote master.

What is the appropriate approach? shall I use push or merge and why?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `git push` to `git merge` is not very sensible:

- The `git push` command is about sending some commit(s) to some other Git that is in charge of some other repository, so that the other repository gets the new commit(s), then asking that other Git to adjust some branch and/or other names in that other repository.
- The `git merge` command is complicated, but when used in one of its typical ways, is about making a new commit in the current branch of your own repository.  This new commit is typically a *merge commit*, with two parents, instead of the more common ordinary commit with one parent.

Now, there are occasions where `git merge` *doesn't* make a new commit, and instead performs a *fast-forward operation*.  A fast-forward operation is a change in a branch name such that the new commit hash ID stored in that name identifies a descendant of the commit whose hash ID was previously stored in that name.  (That's a pretty jargon-heavy statement that requires a bit of graph theory to understand.  See below for a simple example.)

The `git push` command can also be used to send *no* new commits, yet still request that the other Git repository make a change to one of its branch names.  This change can be a fast-forward operation, whether or not your Git sends over any new commits.  In fact, if the branch-name change is a non-fast-forward operation, the `git push` command needs the `--force` or `--force-with-lease` option.

Since both `git merge` and `git push` can engage in this kind of fast-forward action, there *is* at least one case where the two are somewhat comparable.  The key difference for this particular case, though, is that `git merge` performs the fast-forward in *your* repository, and `git push` performs the fast-forward in *some other* Git repository.

The bottom line, as it were, is simple enough:

- If you need to make a merge commit, you *must* do that locally.  The `git push` command cannot do that.
- If you don't need to make a merge commit, ask yourself whose branch name(s) need what kind of update(s).  To update *your own* branch names, work locally.  To update *some other Git repository*, use `git push`.

Remember that repositories share *commits* (by hash IDs), but have *their own private branch names*.  Your names are not anyone else's names, and need not be used the same way—but with humans being humans, we tend to use the same names the same way, because it's too confusing if *I* call you Fred and your co-workers call you Piotr when your name is actually Rahul.

#### Drawing what it means to do a fast-forward

To understand Git's notion of fast-forwards, let's start with the fact that branch names hold commit hash IDs, and commits also hold commit hash IDs.  Whenever something holds a commit hash ID, we say that that something—whatever it is—*points to* that commit.  So a commit points to another commit, and a branch name points to a commit.

The actual name of any given commit is some big ugly hash ID, like [`faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475) for instance.  These are too annoying to type in, and too tricky for humans to remember, so let's draw our own Git commit graph fragments using uppercase letters to stand in for each commit.  Here, we have three commits in a row, with the *last* (latest) one being commit `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Since `H` is the *latest* commit, we'll have a *branch name* point to it:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Meanwhile, commit `H` itself actually stores the raw (and real) hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So `H` points to `G`.  Commit `G`, in turn, stores inside it the hash ID of yet-earlier commit `F`: `G` points to `F`.  This is what we have drawn here.

No part of any commit, once it is made, can ever be changed.  This means we don't really have to draw the internal, backwards-pointing, arrows *between* commits *as* arrows: we can just draw them as connecting lines.  This is useful when we start adding more commits beyond `H`, using another name to find them:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- dev
```

Here, the branch name `dev` points to commit `J`, which points backwards to commit `I`, which points backwards to commit `H`, and so on.  Meanwhile the *name* `master` still points to existing commit `H`.

We can now ask Git to "slide the name `master` forward".  If we move forward just one commit, `master` ends up pointing to `I`, like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
               \
                J   <-- dev
```

Note how the *commits* have not changed: we've just drawn commit `I` one row higher because there's no other good way to draw them on StackOverflow.  The *names* changed, or more precisely, the values stored *in* the name `master` changed, so that `master` now points to `I`.

If we slide `master` all the way forward, we get:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J   <-- dev, master
```

and there's now no reason to keep drawing in the kink at all:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- dev, master
```

suffices.

This operation—moving master "forward" one or more commits—is what Git calls a *fast forward*, because even though `master` now points to `I` or `J`, we can, by starting at whatever commit we find now through that name, work our way backwards to where `master` was before.  It *was* at commit `H`, and `J` points to `I` which points to `H`.  So commit `H` remains *on* the branch named `master`.

But what if we start with this:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
```

then add a new name `dev` also pointing to existing commit `G`:

```
...--F--G   <-- dev, master
```

and then make one new commit on `master`, so that it points to this new commit `H`, but then check out branch `dev` and make one new commit on `dev`, so that `dev` points to new commit `I`?  We will now have:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- dev
```

From `master` (which locates commit `H`), we can work our way back to commit `G`, then commit `F`, and so on.  From `dev`—commit `I`—we can work back to `G` and `F` and so on as well.  But these arrows that connect commits are exclusively *backwards* arrows.  We cannot go "forwards" from `G` to `H`.  Git's connections only point *backwards*.  We need the name `master` so as to find commit `H`, before we go back.

If we force Git to move the name `master` to point to commit `I`, we end up with:

```
          H   ???
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- dev, master
```

The *commit* still exists, but we have no way to find its hash ID.  Commit `H` is lost: it's still there (for a while) but unless we force Git to recover it reasonably quickly, Git will eventually remove it entirely as unnecessary.<sup>1</sup>  This kind of forced name motion, where commit `H` is lost, is a *non-fast-forward*.

If we'd like to join commits `H` and `I` and keep the work done in both, we'll need to use `git merge` (or something similar).

---

<sup>1</sup>In a normal repository, Git leaves traces that will let us recover the commit for at least another 30 days.  In a bare repository on a server, the recovery time is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate approach is to do a `git push`

Why? Because you have a remote and you want to save your current working state to that remote repository. A remote simply helps you save your different commits and current working state.
This serves two good purposes: 1. You are able to collaborate with other team members using the same remote and 2. You can access your repository anywhere even without your local machine.

`git merge` creates a unified branch of the two branches merged. If you do a git merge the files you have on your remote will be merged with your current working files on your local machine.
a `git merge` gets more complicated and mainly works on files on your local machine

Udacity has a free good course on the basics of [git and git hub](https://blog.udacity.com/2015/06/a-beginners-git-github-tutorial.html)